# python parsing item from a list as string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read the contents of a folder and parsing the filenames returned using the following code, I get a type error when executing the code

```
templist = os.listdir(fg_image_dir)

for items in templist:
    #print(items.text)
    print('File  size is '+items.split('_',4))

 print('File  size is '+items.split('_',4)) TypeError: must be str, not list
```

As per the error items is not a str, so I add the line items.text just to see what error message that will produce, the error message is as follows

```
 print(items.text)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Why is a string attribute not considered as string in the first case?

How do I split a filename returned by my code to look for a text pattern

Comment: `str(items.split('_', 4))`

Comment: `items.split('_',4)` returns a `list`. Hence, the error is when you try to concat a list and a str.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your items is a str now, just use

```
print(items)
```

and items.split('_', 4) will return a list, list and can not add with str
if you want to get str has split, you should do this

```
items.split('_',4)[index]
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise its complaining about the new list, newbie error,